# how to import my own package on github action

Tags: python, ubuntu, github-actions

I have a project organized like below:

```
code/
|-- init.py
|-- global_code/
|   |-- all_process.py
|-- africa/
|   |-- egypt/
|   |  |-- egypt_workflow.py
```

I want to run egypt_workflow in all_process (above just a sample, actual there are many countries code)

so I simple added init.py in my 'code' folder
and write

```
import code.africa.egypt.egypt_workflow as ew
```

and it works

however, when i try to run it on github action on ubuntu enviorment, it failed

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'code.africa'; 'code' is not a package
```

I dont know why it happened, so i search online and tried below methods but all failed:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.') # i also tried '..','./','../'
```

got same error

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))
```

still same error

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys
path_root = Path(__file__).parents[2]
sys.path.append(str(path_root))
print(sys.path)
```

still same error, but i found the print result contains below path:

```
/home/runner/work/***/***/code/global_code
```

so i was wondering if the problem was here?

anyway, i also tried change

```
import code.africa.egypt.egypt_workflow as ew
```

to

```
import .code.africa.egypt.egypt_workflow as ew
```

and i got different error

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

so I was wondering if someone could point me to the correct direction?

or maybe i should change my organize way?

Thanks:)

P.S.

I used to use

```
sys.path.append('./code/africa/')
import egypt.egypt_workflow as ee
ee.main()
sys.path.append('./code/asian/')
import japan.japan_workflow as j
j.main()
```

it worked, but as you can see, for each country i have to write one, because many countries not in same continent. So, i want to change to a more elegant way:P

Another P.S.
below is my action code for your reference

```
name: all_action
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: 0 22 * * *
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  all_process: 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: check code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: set up Python 3.10
        uses: actions/setup-Python@v4
        with:
          python-version: 3.10
      - name: install requirements
        run: |
          pip install openpyxl
          pip install -r requirements.txt 
      - name: run code
        run: python ./code/global_code/all_process.py
      - name: commit and push
        run: |
          git config user.name "${GITHUB_ACTOR}"
          git config user.email "${GITHUB_ACTOR}@users.noreply.github.com"
          git add -A
          git commit -m "updated"
          git push
```

Comment: You don't show any of your actions setup; what does the workflow file look like?

Comment: There are any news about this question?